# Apache Spark (Scala): How do I grab a single element and sub-elements from a JSON RDD and store it in a new RDD?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am importing some JSON data from Amazon S3 and storing that in an RDD:

```
val data_sep22 = spark.read.json("s3://firehose-json-events-stream/2019/09/22/*/*")
```

I then take a peak at the data's structure with printSchema()

```
scala> events_sep22.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdAt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- percentage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publishedAt: string (nullable = true)
```

How do I create a new RDD with just `data` and its sub-elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select.

```
events_sep22.select("data").printSchema()

root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- createdAt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- percentage: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)

events_sep22.select("data.*").printSchema()

root
 |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |-- createdAt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- percentage: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```